# I want a select to give me id's that are not in a consecutively order

Tags: oracle, select, order-by

I have an Oracle db with a table like this:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | INDEX |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   0   |
| 1  |   1   |
| 2  |   4   |
| 2  |   5   |
| 2  |   6   |
| 3  |   0   |
| 3  |   1   |
| 3  |   5   |
| 3  |   6   |
| 4  |   0   |
| 4  |   1   |
| 4  |   2   |
+----+-------+
```

I'd want a select to give me all the ID's with INDEX that does not start with 0 or are not in the correct order. From my example I'd want to get 2,3.
THANKS!

Comment: What do you mean buy 2,3? ID 2 with 3 indexes?

Comment: He means ids 2 and 3 since both violate the rule for the indices

Comment: Do not think that is what he means. 1,3, and 4 start with 0 so they are not valid. Only 2 does not start with 0 and 4, 5, and 6 are consecutive.

Comment: 2 does not start with 0 and 3 does not have idx consecutives, 1 and 4 are ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   create table index_test(id number, idx number);

   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (1,0);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (1,1);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (1,2);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (1,3);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (1,4);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (2,0);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (2,1);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (2,2);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (2,4);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (2,5);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (3,1);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (3,2);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (3,3);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (3,4);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (3,5);
   insert into index_test (id, idx) values (3,6);

select id from index_test group by id having max(idx)+1!=count(*) or min(idx)!=0;
```

Comment: In the example ID 2 has 4,5, and 6 and it is expected in the outcome.

Comment: Yes. Hence min(idx)!=0 which means it shows up

Comment: What if you have only index 4 and 6? Is this acceptable?

Comment: No. It neither starts with 0 nor is it consequtive

Comment: ID 2 with 4,6, and 6 is not returned by your solution. `max(idx)` is 6 and `count(*)` is only 3.

Comment: Idk what you mean. You must have misunderstood something. It is definitely returned by my solution since min(idx) is 4, which is not 0

Comment: Question was not clear. Yours must be correct since he accepted it as a solution. A NOT followed by an OR always gives problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select   id
from     tab
where    id not in (select id
                    from   tab
                    where  index=0)
group by id
having   max(index)+1!=count(*)
order by id;
```

Preventing that the combination of id and index is unique

Answer (score -1):

```
    DECLARE @Line TABLE(Id INT)


INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (5)
INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (7)
INSERT INTO @Line (Id) VALUES (9)




;WITH CTE as 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER    (ORDER BY Id) as RowId, Id FROM @Line
)
SELECT * FROM CTE where RowId <> Id
```

Hope it helps,

If its repeating then you can use rank or partition by

Maulin.

Comment: This syntax isn't going to work on Oracle.